# How to stop iOS EAGLContext's memory from growing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, opengl-es

In this super simple app that uses a GLKViewController to display a red screen the memory keeps growing.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController {
    EAGLContext* context;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    GLKView* view = (GLKView*)self.view;
    view.context = context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableColorFormatRGBA8888;
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context];

    self.preferredFramesPerSecond = 60;
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

For each frame 9*64 bytes is allocated and never freed as seen in this image (note that the transient count is 0 for IOAccellResource):

[image: IOAccellResource allocations keeps growing]

This is what the allocation list and stacktrace looks like:

[image: Allocation list and stacktrace]

The memory "leak" is small but it still managed to use up 6.5 MB despite only running for less than 3 minutes.

Is there a bug in the EAGLContext or is there something I can do about this? I have noticed (I'm new to iOS development) that other parts of Apple's API uses zone allocators and the memory usage keeps growing when it really should have been in some kind of steady state mode. That makes me think I have missed something (I have tried to send it LowMemory but nothing happen).

Comment: Not an answer but just a suggestion: Never ever under any circumstances use GLKView, GLKViewController or any other GLKit components that are in Objective-C. Only use matrices, vectors... Not only this components are evil and unpredictable but also you may quickly limit your progress when you try to do something custom.

Comment: For the actual rendering I use C++. But I must at least use `[EAGLContext presentRenderBuffer]` to do the "buffer swap", right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I printed out the amount of resident memory to the screen and noticed that the memory didn't increase when the device was disconnected from the debugger.

It turns out that using the "Zombie instrument" was causing this... I swear that I saw the memory increase in the memory view of the debugger too, but now I can't repeat it (haven't changed anything in the scheme).

Answer (score 0):

So from your comment you say that you are using some other code that is written in C++ and basically all you need is the connection to the actual buffer to be presented. I will assume none of that "C++" code you mentioned is inflating your memory and you have actually try to create a new application only adding the code you posted just to be 100% sure...

To migrate off the `GLKit` is then very easy for you. Simply subclass the `UIView` which will be used to drawing and add a few methods:

This needs to be overridden so you can get the render buffer from the view

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
        return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

The context is already done correctly and needs to be used.

You need to setup the buffers manually. I use a custom class but I believe you will be able to see what is going on here and possibly remove the code you don't need.

```
- (void)loadBuffersWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.view = view;

    CAEAGLLayer *layer = (CAEAGLLayer *)view.layer;
    layer.opaque = YES;

    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)]) {
        layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    }

    GLuint frameBuffer; // will hold the generated ID
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer); // generate only 1
    self.frameBuffer = frameBuffer; // assign to store as the local variable
    [self bindFrameBuffer];

    GLuint renderBuffer; // will hold the generated ID
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &renderBuffer); // generate only 1
    self.renderBuffer = renderBuffer; // assign to store as the local variable
    [self bindRenderBuffer];

    [self.context.glContext renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:layer];

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, self.renderBuffer);

    GLint width, height;
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &width);
    glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &height);
    self.bufferSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    [GlobalTools framebufferStatusValid];
    [GlobalTools checkError];
}
```

On present you need to call `presentRenderbuffer` on your context with the appropriate render buffer id.

Rest of your code should be the same. But remember to also tear down the openGL when you do not need it and possibly explicitly delete all the buffers that were generated on the GPU.

Comment: Yes, I created a new project without my C++ stuff to be sure that it wasn't my code that created the leak in some obscure way.
I found an example project from Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLEssentials/Introduction/Intro.html) that does what you do. But really, is Apple's stuff so bad that you need to rewrite everything yourself to avoid that a memory leak limits the time a customer can use my app in one strech!?

Comment: Well, the code I posted is field tested and should give you no memory leak.

Comment: Now I have implemented the rendering without using GLKit. But I still get the same leak, which isn't super surprising since the leak happen in code called by `presentRenderbuffer`. What iOS version are you running on? I'm using 9.0.2 

You said "The context is already done correctly and needs to be used", does that mean that there is an `EAGLContext` instance ready somewhere (I create a new instance in `initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder` in the view)?

Comment: I ment the same context you have already done... Anyway I just created a new application using the code posted above, using a display link to animate the clear color and presenting the render buffer at 60 FPS. I have tested on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 while connected to Xcode, in simulator and none of them have any memory leak, the memory does not inflate at all. Is there anything else you are doing? Maybe you have some snapshots enabled for debugger to collect them.

Comment: I printed out the amount of resident memory to the screen and noticed that the memory didn't increase when the device was disconnected from the debugger. It turns out that using the "Zombie instrument" was causing this... I swear that I saw the memory increase in the memory view of the debugger too, but now I can't repeat it (haven't changed anything in the scheme). Anyway, thanks for spending time with this. If you add another answer suggesting to I don't use the Zombie instrument I will accept that.

Comment: You should probably just close it or write the answer yourself since you figured it out yourself... It doesn't seem like much of a contribution to other developers anyway.